More than 2 dimensions in Google Analytics Core reporting API
I'm downloading my old Universal Analytics data, since it will be deleted after 1st July. I'm doing this using the package GoogleAnalyticsR in R using the function google_analytics_data. This makes use of the Core Reporting API V4. In the documentation of this API, they say that you can supply a maximum of 7 dimensions and 10 metrics per query.
As an example, I run the query with the metric 'ga:sessions' and the dimensions 'ga:country', 'ga:medium' and 'ga:source'. This works when I select a timeframe of one day after 2022-03-01. However, when I run the same query with a timeframe before this date, the query returns 0 rows. Some trial and error seems to show that the maximum number of dimensions in this older timeperiod is not 7, but 2.
Therefore I have two questions:

Can anyone confirm this?
Does anybody know if there's a workaround for this? Of course I can get creative with filters, but unfortunately I'm quite restricted by the quota limit.

